# Flex div not wrapping text in IE11 but in Chrome, FF and Opera

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**HTML**

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
    <div style="flex: 0 0 20px;">top</div>
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
        <div style="flex: 0 0 30px;">left</div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 auto;     display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
            <div style="flex: 0 0 100px;">header</div>

            <!-- text is not wrapping inside this cell in IE11 -->
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vehicula ante eget aliquam semper. Vestibulum aliquam rhoncus sem nec tristique.</div>

            <div style="flex: 0 0 100px;">footer</div>
        </div>
        <div style="flex: 0 0 30px;">right</div>
    </div>
    <div style="flex: 0 0 20px;">bottom</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle working in FF and Chrome but not in IE11:

http://jsfiddle.net/uu0uqkfo/

What should I do to get the text inside the inner div to wrap in IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `flex: 1;` instead of `flex: 1 1 auto;` for the div containing header, main and footer:

```css
div {
    border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
        <div style="flex: 0 0 20px;">top</div>
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
            <div style="flex: 0 0 30px;">left</div>
            <div style="flex: 1;  display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                <div style="flex: 0 0 100px;">header</div>
                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vehicula ante eget aliquam semper. Vestibulum aliquam rhoncus sem nec tristique. </div>
                <div style="flex: 0 0 100px;">footer</div>
            </div>
            <div style="flex: 0 0 30px;">right</div>
        </div>
        <div style="flex: 0 0 20px;">bottom</div>
    </div>
```

With this only change, the everything works as expected in IE 11.

Comment: This sure works. I know it's short for `flex: 1 1 0px`. Can you please explain why it works? I just don't get what the `flex-basis: 0px` means.

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex: 1;` instead of `flex: 1 1 auto;`

See the updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/uu0uqkfo/1/